# When stdout is being used to output binary data, how can I also output debug/verbose info to the terminal?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

I'm writing an application that will open a file and output some processed version. It will be a graphical desktop application, but must also be suitable for running on a web server. It therefore needs to provide a suitable interface for a web app's back-end code (which will likely be PHP).

I decided the most versatile kind of interface was a CLI, where the program is invoked once per file. The generated data is piped out via stdout. This way, no temporary files have to be created; it all happens in memory.

I'd like to be able to invoke the program manually from the terminal and see a verbose debug output. In general, when stdout is being used for outputting a data stream, what's the conventional way of outputting other information? Should I use stderr or is there another way? I'll like to be able to invoke the program like so and see some debug output.

./program --some-option --verbose --file="./myfile.txt" > ./output.txt

Can I use file descriptor 3 (or some other number) for the binary data and stdout for the verbose info and do this?

./program --some-option --verbose --file="./myfile.txt" 3> ./output.txt

Thanks

Comment: Why not use stderr? But I would use files for output and introduce parameters to enable them

Comment: `stderr` or a log file are the two common solutions.

Comment: @Marged Yes, come to think of it, that's the norm isn't it? So on the server it would output the binary data to stdout, but when invoked on the terminal you'd say --output-file=output.txt or something and get debug info to stdout. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice to use stderr and stdout to separate different kinds of output.

But preferably you should use parameters to allow the user specify where and if to write the output of a certain category.
You could use something like `--enable-verbose-output` or `--processing-log=foo.log`

You might also consider handling this within the log file you perhaps create already. By setting a certain verbosity in the logging framework you could write the desired output into your log as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use stderr:

```
./program --some-option --verbose --file="./myfile.txt" > ./output.txt 2> ./debug.out
```